# Binding Spotify iOS SDK to C# using Objective Sharpie

Tags: c#, ios, mono, xamarin.ios, xamarin

I'm trying to use Xamarin's Objective Sharpie to create C# bindings to Spotify's Library.  I was able to get it to work for the Adobe Foundation Framework as found in the example.  But have not been able to get Objective Sharpie to do it.  I've used a few commands, which I'll show below that result in a binding error.

**1) First I tried the simple approach:**

```
sharpie bind -framework Spotify.framework/ -sdk iphoneos8.2
```

Error: : Umbrella header file does not exist: Spotify.framework/Headers/.h

**2) Next, I tried their more involved example and came out with this...**

```
sharpie bind \
-sdk iphoneos8.2 Spotify.framework/Headers/Spotify.h \
-scope Spotify.framework/Headers \
-c -F
```

Error: no sources specified

I'm going to continue to plug away to see what else I can figure out.  Any help would be greatly appreciated!  Thanks!

**More Information:**
I'm using Beta7 of Spotify iOS SDK, and Objective Sharpie 2.1.6.

Spotify iOS SDK Framework
https://developer.spotify.com/technologies/spotify-ios-sdk/

Objective Sharpie on Native Frameworks
http://developer.xamarin.com/guides/ios/advanced_topics/binding_objective-c/objective_sharpie/#Binding_Native_Frameworks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> sharpie bind -sdk iphoneos8.2 -framework Spotify.framework

was fine with me. Check if you have iPhone 8.2 SDK installed on your machine.

> xcodebuild -showsdks

if no, you can install it from Xcode - Preferences - Downloads.

Comment: Thanks for your time, apparently I was silly and was thinking the \ was a / and added that to the end of my Spotify.framework, which made it glitch.  I feel silly.  Yours worked, and thanks again! :)

Comment: To download an old sdk, you will have to go to the apple developer downloads.